# Modification of .htaccess file, desktop version works, mobile dont, 500 error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, optimization

When i pasted this code into my .htaccess file, everything works fine on my desktop version.

```
 # Optimize cache-control
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType image/gif “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType image/png “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType image/jpg “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType image/jpeg “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType text/html “access plus 3 days”
ExpiresByType text/xml “access plus 1 seconds”
ExpiresByType text/plain “access plus 1 seconds”
ExpiresByType application/xml “access plus 1 seconds”
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml “access plus 1 seconds”
ExpiresByType application/json “access plus 1 seconds”
ExpiresByType text/css “access plus 1 week”
ExpiresByType text/javascript “access plus 1 week”
ExpiresByType application/javascript “access plus 1 week”
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript “access plus 1 week”
ExpiresByType image/x-ico “access plus 1 year”
ExpiresByType image/x-icon “access plus 1 year”
ExpiresByType application/pdf “access plus 1 month”
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header unset Pragma
Header unset Last-Modified
Header append Cache-Control “public, no-transform, must-revalidate”
Header set Last-modified “Mon, 1 Oct 2018 10:10:10 GMT”
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

On another hand for mobile I have 500 error.

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at
>   webmaster to inform them of the time this error
>   occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Try to change all `“` and `”` to `"`

Comment: That was a case.